# How to continue promise chain after retry?

Tags: angularjs, angular-promise, restangular

I'm using restangular to make multiple calls to my backend, I have a dependency on the result of the first call to execute subsequent calls.

I'm trying to setup retry logic so follow on requests are executed after retry succeeds. Here's my code so far:

```
reefService.createGitLabProject(formData)
  .then(function(apiResponse) {
    $scope.apiStatus.messages.push({'direction': 'in', 'body': apiResponse.result});
    $scope.progressValue += 1;
    var gitLabProject = {
      'id': apiResponse.data.id,
      'http_url_to_repo': apiResponse.data.http_url_to_repo,
      'ssh_url_to_repo': apiResponse.data.ssh_url_to_repo
    };
    // add deploy key
    reefService.addGitLabDeployKey(gitLabProject)
      .then(function(apiResponse) {
        $scope.apiStatus.messages.push({'direction': 'in', 'body': apiResponse.result});
        $scope.progressValue += 1;
      })
      .catch(function(apiError) {
        $scope.apiStatus.errors.push(apiError);
      });
    // add web hook
    reefService.addGitLabProjectHook(gitLabProject)
      .then(function(apiResponse) {
        $scope.apiStatus.messages.push({'direction': 'in', 'body': apiResponse.result});
        $scope.progressValue += 1;
      })
      .catch(function(apiError) {
        $scope.apiStatus.errors.push(apiError);
      });
  // failed to create project
  })
  .catch(function(apiError) {
    $scope.apiStatus.errors.push(apiError);
  });
```

retry is called manually, it is passed `apiError` restangular object from `$scope.apiStatus.errors`. I'm using following:

```
$scope.retryRequest = function(error){
 var restAngularConf = error.config;
 $http(restAngularConf)
  .then(function(apiResponse) {
    $scope.progressValue += 1;
    // add response to messages
    $scope.apiStatus.messages.push({'direction': 'in', 'body': apiResponse.data.result});
    // delete error from errors array
    var ix = $scope.apiStatus.errors.indexOf(error);
    $scope.apiStatus.errors.splice(ix, 1);
  })
  .catch(function(apiError) {
    toaster.pop('error', 'Retry Error', apiError.data.message);
  });
};
```

It basically receives `apiError` and runs `$http` call using data in `apiError.config` (url, post data etc.). This works fine for calls with no dependencies like `addGitLabDeployKey` and `addGitLabProjectHook`, I'm having trouble working out how to setup `createGitLabProject` so that after its error is passed to `$scope.retryRequest` and request completes, `addGitLabDeployKey` and `addGitLabProjectHook` continue.

How can I setup `$q` service in `createGitLabProject` so request chain continues after retry?

Thanks very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

It appears I'm missing the point of promises, I'd need to wrap this in the function and pass the function to retry array and retry it this way...